# Filter a dataGrid with a comboBox in flex

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, filtering

How can I filter a datagrid based on the value in the combo box? Can anyone show me some good examples on it?

In my application, I already filter a datagrid based on the text entered by the user. I check if the entered string matches the column entry of the datagrid and if a match is found,the filterFunction on the dataprovider is called. All this I did with the help of a tutorial only, as I'm learning flex as I do my project.

This is that code:

```
<mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
    <mx:ComboBox id="searchCriteria1" dataProvider="{criteriaDP1}" change="searchFunction()"/>
    <mx:TextInput id="search" change="searchFunction()"/> 
    <mx:Button label="Clear Search" click="clear()" /> 
</mx:FormItem> 

private function searchFunction():void{
defectList.filterFunction = filterItems;
defectList.refresh();
}

private function filterItems(item:Object):Boolean
{
var isMatch:Boolean = false         

     if(searchCriteria1.selectedItem.label == "Defect Id")
{ 
    if(item.defId.toString().search(search.text.toString()) != -1)
    {
        isMatch = true
    } 
}
else if(searchCriteria1.selectedItem.label == "Review Id")
{
    if(item.revId.toString().search(search.text.toString()) != -1)
    {
        isMatch = true
    } 
}
     return isMatch;  

}
```

Here defectList is the dataprovider to the Data Grid, revId,defId are the columns of the data grid  .

Now how do I filter, with combo boxes. I have a combo box called "priority" with values "high","medium","low","all". If I select all,no filtering is done. If I select "high" only those fields with priprity column value as "high" should appear.

**EDIT**
I even tried like this:

```
 if(searchCriteria2.selectedItem.label=="Priority")
 {
      if (item.revType.toLowerCase().search(searchCriteria.selectedLabel.toLowerCase()) != -1)
 {
              Alert("yes");
    isMatch=true
 }
 }
```

searchCriteria is the comboBox,where I have the items, "ALL","HIGH"... 
I have two rows with value "high" and I get the Alert "yes" for two times only..
But in the data grid all the four rows are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be searching on the revType column, rather than the Priority column.

It may be worth finding a way to reduce the amount of duplicated code in your app to help avoid bugs like this. For example, your list of fields could look like this:

```
[Bindable]
var criteriaDP1:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{label:"Review ID", value:"RevID"},
                                                       {label:"Defect Id", value:"DefID"}]);
```

Setting it up like that would let you use the `value` field as an index on your dataProvider, like this:

```
public function search_clickHandler():void
{
    defectList.filterFunction = function(item:Object):Boolean
    {
        var gridValue:String = item[searchCriteria.selectedItem.value].toString().toLowerCase();
        var searchValue:String = search.text.toLowerCase(); 
        if(gridValue.search(searchValue) != -1)
        {
            return true;                        
        }
        return false;
    };
    defectList.refresh();
}
```